# Embed text files in html

Tags: html, text, embed, text-files

I would like to display the content of a text file inside a HTML page (`.rtf`, `.txt`, `.log`,...) stored on the server.

I have tried with `embed` but seems that doesn't work.

```
<embed src="/path_to_text_file/text.rtf" width="500" height="300">
```

There is a "simple" method (or tag) to do that or I should scan for the content and print it with, for example, jQuery?

Comment: @Dvir with object it starts automatically the download without showing me the content of the file

Comment: Do you mean embedding or inclusion? RTF or plain text? Different things.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela displaying the content of the file. All kind of "simples" text format (.rtf,.txt,.log,...)

Comment: Then the question is too broad.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela don't think so broad, we are talking about only for text -base- files (no word, no pdf, no ppt,...) that aren't "encoded". The accepted answer works well.

Comment: Why doesn't embed work?

Comment: @CraigHicks if I remember correctly what I did 5 years ago ;-) with the embed tag it started the download of the file instead displaying the content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a $.ajax() function with a .append() function inside you can easily grab the contents of a text document and display them on the page. Something along the lines of what you see below. Preform this on load of the page to immediately load the file in with the rest of the page.

```
$.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: 'folder/file.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) 
        {
        $('element').append(data);
            }
        });
```

Play around with it a little bit to get the correct result you are looking for. You could also use PHP but unless you really need to parse the data, PHP is a bit overkill in this situation.

Comment: This is inclusion, not embedding. Maybe what was actually wanted, but not what was asked.

Comment: Ha sorry damoiser, but glad it works for you. You could also use a $.get() request, I just figured I'd give you the original ajax request that has more options you can control.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this should do it:

```
<object data="/path_to_text_file/text.txt" type="text/plain"
width="500" style="height: 300px">
<a href="/path_to_text_file/text.txt">No Support?</a>
</object>
```

Comment: with Chrome unfortunely doesn't work, it seems that starts automatically the download without showing the content

Comment: The code posted works well. Similar code for an RTF file might not.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela tested with a .rtf file

Comment: This works in Chrome 63. However, you do have to wait for the document to load. E.g., from within a `window.onload` event, do `data.contentDocument.body.textContent.trim()`, where `data` is a reference to your `object` element. Also, you probably want zero width and height on your `object` element (but not `style="display:none"` — that will break it).

Comment: Didn't work for me. I think modern browsers have stricter securities and have blocked this. What I do is store data in a javascript file and load it in <script> tag

Answer (score 4):

An iFrame might be useful in this context.

```html
<iframe src="/path_to_text_file/text.rtf" width="500" height="300" frameBorder="0">
```

Comment: I upvoted this solution as it is much more flexibel and commonly-used, than the object html element. It can also be used as overlay and has scrollbars, what is off-topic...

Answer (score 3):

is only for plugin content (flash, etc).
Try getting content using ajax, then write it with `document.write`;
Or use the `include` tag in a back end language (PHP, ASP, etc)

Comment: +1 to give me the right direction to work, Keith V wins the best answer because he gives to me a more complete solution than yours

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: apologies for the similarity to Keith V's answer and the fact he mentioned get requests - I only noticed his comment about get requests after posting my answer.

I find the following structure helpful, and allows me to style the text as a span rather than having to wield an object:

```js
function append_url_content_to_div(url){
  $.get(url, function(returned_data){
    console.dir(returned_data);
    var content = '<span>'+returned_data+'</span>';
    $("#appendee_div").append(content);        
  });
}
append_url_content_to_div("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/euk874r7zd1cx0d/example_text.txt?dl=0"); //note that it has to be "dl." not "www." in dropbox
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendee_div"></div>
```

It works for me for dropbox content, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for publicly viewable text files. As you can see in the code, you need jquery.

Answer (score -2):

I found the best way to insert HTML5 code into a website is to save the code onto a new text document and embed that document using `<embed src="textdoc.txt" height="500" width="500">`. Then you can format the code using css and divs.

Comment: embed that document using *what*?

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, as I think people had downvoted because Stack Overflow had stripped out the code. (The code would have been accessible by clicking on "Edit" or "Improve this answer") (Of course the answer is the same as what is stated in the question, but maybe it didn't work in browsers when the question was asked…)

Answer (score -4):

Just use php. Change the html format to php and use

> echo file_get_contents("name_of_the_file.txt");

Simple as that.
You must use php because you have to output your text on the server side unless the info will not be shown to the client.

I think is the easiest way to do what you want.

Comment: I don't think that I must use a server side language programming like PHP, ASP, AngularJS,.. sure it is easier but my question was how implement this only in client side. See the accepted solution